# Bootstrap Form Layout (Desktop vs Mobile Inputs Order)

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that on desktop is displayed in 4 columns. (Bootstrap CSS). I have problem with displaying  it on the mobile with the right order. Take a look at numbered order of inputs grouped by divs (differnet colors on the screenshot). How do I achive the order as on attached screenshot (Moble View)?

[image]

My Basic Bootsrap:

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
1
2
3
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
4
5
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
6
7
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
10
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
11
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
8
9
12
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is to just follow Simple Grid System of *Bootstrap* as below snippet

### Code Snipppet

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="1" class="form-control" />
    <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="2" class="form-control" />
    <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="3" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="4" class="form-control" />
        <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="5" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="6" class="form-control" />
        <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="7" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="8" class="form-control" />
        <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="9" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="10" class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="11" class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <input name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="12" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/y79LwL9x)

Comment: sorry @vivekkupadhyay I messed up my question (wrong required order). I just updated the the question . Please take look an order of inputs again.

Comment: I think I have given you enough code to play with, go on and try you will achieve that easily.

Comment: that would be really great :)

Comment: ok. i just do not know how to make it. Pls check js fiddle, input error text message should be right on top of the button.